# Sequelize Seeder Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize with postgres and this is my first time using seeders. I just migrated data and have already set up my database to receive data. I am able to upload data through my frontend via a form post. For some reason though, my seeder keeps failing. The only error I am getting is "ERROR: unexpected identifier".

I have checked numerous times and had other people check to make sure my table and columns are spelled correctly. I have done the same with the syntax.

My seeder. (Yes, my table name is lowercase and plural. Sue me.)

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.bulkInsert(
      "potatoes",
      [
        {name: "Yukon Gold", starch_level: "All Purpose", cook_method: "boil, bake, fry", createdAt: New Date(), updatedAt: New Date()},
        {name: "Purple Peruvian", starch_level: "All Purpose", cook_method: "boil, bake, fry, roast, grill", createdAt: New Date(), updatedAt: New Date()},
        {name: "Idaho Russet", starch_level: "Starchy", cook_method: "bake, mash, fry", createdAt: New Date(), updatedAt: New Date()},
        {name: "Katahdin", starch_level: "Starchy", cook_method: "boil, bake, fry", createdAt: New Date(), updatedAt: New Date()},
        {name: "Red Bliss", starch_level: "Waxy", cook_method: "soup, stew, boil, roast, salad, casserole", createdAt: New Date(), updatedAt: New Date()},
        {name: "New Potato", starch_level: "Waxy", cook_method: "boil, steam, roast", createdAt: New Date(), updatedAt: New Date()},
        {name: "Adirondack Blue", starch_level: "Waxy", cook_method: "mash, bake, boil, steam, salad, casserole, gratin", createdAt: New Date(), updatedAt: New Date()},
        {name: "Adirondack Red", starch_level: "Waxy", cook_method: "boil, mash, fry", createdAt: New Date(), updatedAt: New Date()},
        {name: "Fingerling", starch_level: "Waxy", cook_method: "boil, bake, roast, salad", createdAt: New Date(), updatedAt: New Date()},
        {name: "Carola", starch_level: "Waxy", cook_method: "grill, roast, boil, fry, salad, casserole, gratin", createdAt: New Date(), updatedAt: New Date()},
        {name: "Inca Gold", starch_level: "Waxy", cook_method: "roast, mash, boil, salad, casserole, gratin", createdAt: New Date(), updatedAt: New Date()},
        {name: "Rose Gold", starch_level: "Waxy", cook_method: "bake, steam, boil, salad, casserole, gratin", createdAt: New Date(), updatedAt: New Date()},
        {name: "Purple Viking", starch_level: "Waxy", cook_method: "bake, roast, boil, salad, casserole, gratin", createdAt: New Date(), updatedAt: New Date()}
      ],
      {}
    );
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.bulkDelete("potatoes", null, {})
  }
};
```

The terminal command.

```
sequelize db:seed:all
```

I've also attempted --seed file_name, to no avail.

Error message every time.

```
ERROR: unexpected identifier
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to rename

> **New** Date()
>   to
>   **new** Date()

Comment: Wow. I have brought shame to my family. Thank you.

Comment: We learn from mistakes. Nothing to be ashamed of, cheers and Happy Coding.
Don't forget to upvote if it worked.